# ruby 1.9.3 simple GET request to unicorn through socket

Tags: ruby, sockets

Now I try to connect to my socket cretaed by unicorn with this code

```
require 'socket'

def foo
  socket = UNIXSocket.new("path_to_socket/tmp/unicorn.sock")

  data = "GET /time HTTP/1.1\n" 
  data << "Connection: Close\n" 
  data << "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\n" 
  data << "Accept: */*\n" 
  data << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n" 
  data << "\n\r\n\r"

  socket.puts(data)

  while(line = socket.gets) do
    puts line
  end 
end

foo
```

But always get a "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Please, can any body say what I'm do wrong???

Comment: Since others have pointed out alternatives that don't involve writing your own request, I'll try to summarize what's wrong with the request you've come up with. 1: Your headers are terminated by `\n`; they should actually be terminated by `\r\n`. 2: In a similar vein, you should be using `\r\n\r\n`, not `\n\r\n\r`, to terminate your request. 3: Every server I've ever thrown a hand-written HTTP request at required the `Host` header to be given, even those that don't actually give a rat's ass about its value - something along the lines of `Host: localhost` should work just fine in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use net/http...

```
require "net/http"
require "socket"

sock = Net::BufferedIO.new(UNIXSocket.new("path_to_socket/tmp/unicorn.sock"))
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/time")
request.exec(sock, "1.1", "/time")

begin
  response = Net::HTTPResponse.read_new(sock)
end while response.kind_of?(Net::HTTPContinue)
response.reading_body(sock, request.response_body_permitted?) { }

response.body
response.code
```

Comment: Anyone getting 400 Bad Request when trying this:
Note that all HTTP/1.1 requests MUST specify a `Host:` header as per RFC 2616. For HTTP/1.0 requests the only real option is to serve the "primary" host result. This question specifically addresses HTTP/1.1 protocol requests. From question [14705659](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705659/returning-400-in-virtual-host-environments-where-host-header-has-no-match)

Comment: Also note that the HTTPGenericRequest#exec, while its access is public, it is [marked as](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/Net/HTTPGenericRequest.html#exec-instance_method) `:nodoc: internal use only` so it doesn't show up in API docs and might change over time.

Answer (score 2):

This is very helpful but please note that the Net::HTTP#exec method is marked *for internal use only*.  Likely because it doesn't do resource management, etc.

The following work adapts the suggested strategy to override Net::HTTP#connect (to connect to a socket).  I like to use the [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) for handling my HTTP requests.  So the strategy here makes use of a custom ConnectionAdaptor for HTTParty.  Now I can just change the ::default_params= call on my including class, to control whether we're using a Unix or a TCP/HTTP socket.

```
###########################################################
#  net/socket_http.rb
###########################################################

module Net
  #  Overrides the connect method to simply connect to a unix domain socket.
  class SocketHttp < HTTP
    attr_reader :socket_path

    #  URI should be a relative URI giving the path on the HTTP server.
    #  socket_path is the filesystem path to the socket the server is listening to.
    def initialize(uri, socket_path)
      @socket_path = socket_path
      super(uri)
    end

    #  Create the socket object.
    def connect
      @socket = Net::BufferedIO.new UNIXSocket.new socket_path
      on_connect
    end

    #  Override to prevent errors concatenating relative URI objects.
    def addr_port
      File.basename(socket_path)
    end
  end
end


###########################################################
#  sock_party.rb, a ConnectionAdapter class
###########################################################
require "net/http"
require "socket"

class SockParty < HTTParty::ConnectionAdapter
  #  Override the base class connection method.
  #  Only difference is that we'll create a Net::SocketHttp rather than a Net::HTTP.
  #  Relies on :socket_path in the
  def connection
    http = Net::SocketHttp.new(uri, options[:socket_path])

    if options[:timeout] && (options[:timeout].is_a?(Integer) || options[:timeout].is_a?(Float))
      http.open_timeout = options[:timeout]
      http.read_timeout = options[:timeout]
    end

    if options[:debug_output]
      http.set_debug_output(options[:debug_output])
    end

    if options[:ciphers]
      http.ciphers = options[:ciphers]
    end

    return http
  end
end


###########################################################
#  class MockSockParty, a really *nix-y HTTParty
###########################################################
class MockSockParty
  include HTTParty
  self.default_options = {connection_adapter: SockParty, socket_path: '/tmp/thin.sock'}

  def party_hard
    self.class.get('/client').body
  end
end

###########################################################
#  sock_party_spec.rb
###########################################################

require 'spec_helper'

describe SockParty do
  it "should party until its socks fall off." do
    puts MockSockParty.new.party_hard
  end
end
```